# Remove all spaces from lines starting with specific word

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Regex find/replace in Notepadd++ how can I remove all spaces from a line if the line starts with 'CHAPTER'?

Example Text:

```
CHAPTER A B C
Once upon a time.
```

What I want to end up with:

```
CHAPTERABC
Once upon a time.
```

Incorrect code is something like:

```
(?<=CHAPTER)( )(?<=\r\n)
```

So 'CHAPTER' needs to stay and the search should stop at the first line break.

Comment: What is your environment? Try `(?:^CHAPTER|(?!^)\G)\S*\K\h+`. What does you sample text look like?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question. Your suggestion works good - can you add this as the answer with a little explanation on how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `\G` based regex to only match a line that starts with `CHAPTER` and then match only consecutive non-whitespace and whitespace chunks up to the linebreak while omitting the matched non-whitespace chunks and removing only the horizontal whitespace:

```
(?:^CHAPTER|(?!^)\G)\S*\K\h+
```

**Details**:

- `(?:^CHAPTER|(?!^)\G)` - `CHAPTER` at the start of a line (`^CHAPTER`) or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (`(?!^)\G`, as `\G` can also match the start of a line, we use the retricting negative lookahead.)
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace symbols
- `\K` - a match reset operator forcing the regex engine omit the text matched so far (thus, we do not remove `CHAPTER` or any of the non-whitespace chunks)
- `\h+` - horizontal whitespace (1 or more occurrences) only

[image]